# beautiful soup remove HTML tags from findAll results

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.horoscope.com/us/horoscopes/general/horoscope-general-daily-today.aspx?sign=1"
page = requests.get(url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

horoscope = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "block-horoscope-text f16 l20"}, text=True)
```

But the returned result includes the  tag as well.

```
<div class="block-horoscope-text f16 l20">
            It could be scary for you to do anything risky for fear of conflict or failure, Aries. Perhaps you've tried to become invisible in different situations so you can avoid being noticed. These defense mechanisms may serve you for a while, but acting out of fear or guilt won't get you where you need to go. To achieve what you want, you must act with confidence, love, and faith.
        </div>
```

How do I remove them? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `[0].text`, hope this help !

```
horoscope = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "block-horoscope-text f16 l20"}, text=True)[0].text
print(horoscope)
```

Comment: Welcome :) @CodesInTheValley

Comment: also if you want to eliminate whitespaces, `print(str(horoscope).strip())`